# Java EE Shared Libs?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classpath, shared-libraries

I'm having trouble getting a shared library working in a Java EE environment.

In particular, the library contains some helpers for common JMS activities. However, as soon as the code enters a library function that requires anything from `javax.jms` it's triggering a `ClassNotFound` exception (claiming it can't find `javax.jms.Message`, for instance.)

How do I get around this? I'm placing the shared lib under `$AS_HOME\lib\endorsed` -- does it belong elsewhere? I have tried also packaging all the dependencies inside the jar; this doesn't seem to make much of a difference.

I am really hoping this is much more straightforward than it is seeming right now. In order just to get it working, I've refactored the helper into a helper-per-module within each component that requires the functionality. Note that this is working, so I'm thinking the issue at this point is just classpath problems? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Whats AS are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to put the jms.jar in:

```
 $AS_HOME/domains/<your domain>/lib
```

but you could always just place them in:

```
$AS_HOME/lib/
```

If you are not familiar with domains, take a quick glance at [Concept of a GlassFish Domain](http://blogs.oracle.com/bloggerkedar/entry/concept_of_a_glassfish_domain)